# expected number of of intersections of independent brownian motions on the line

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

I'm kind of surprised that I've been unable to find a closed form for the expected number of intersections of $n$ independent standard Brownian motions up to time $t > 0$. I'm well aware of the Karlin-McGregor formula which gives the asymptotics of non-intersecting Brownian motions as $t\to\infty$. I have been looking mostly at the literature for coalescing Brownian motions, but the asymptotics are not very precise. Any suggestions?